# jekyll installed but 'command not found'

Tags: terminal, osx-mountain-lion, jekyll

I installed [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), but surprisingly somehow osx doesn't recognise its installed.

```
$ sudo gem install jekyll
Password:
Successfully installed jekyll-1.2.1
Parsing documentation for jekyll-1.2.1
Done installing documentation for jekyll after 1 seconds
1 gem installed

$ jekyll
-bash: jekyll: command not found

gem environment ( - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0 )

$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/
```

[image]

```
echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/Users/TheSpiritMolecule/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/TheSpiritMolecule/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: a friend found the solution for my case, regarding issues with OS X freaking Captain: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33059347/274502

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay I had to check what exatly does the $PATH means, and for what it is.

The problem was simple, somehow my ruby installion directory wasnt in my $path variable.

Useful links: [Mac OS X: Set / Change $PATH Variable](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/)

Okay so here is the thing how I solved it:

```
echo "$PATH"
gem uninstall jekyll
find / -name jekyll (to delete if there is any leftovers somewhere )
gem environment ( get EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY path )
nano $HOME/.bash_profile ( go to the end of document and insert a new line )
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin:$PATH"
```

you can do this on a templorary way by just writing it in terminal and not saving it in your `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 20):

I have rbenv installed and the step I missed was to do an `rbenv rehash` after `gem install jekyll`. The rehash creates a link in ~/.rbenv/shims which is in included in $PATH.

Comment: Sweet!  For reference the rbenv docs say "Run this command (rehash) after you install a new version of Ruby, or install a gem that provides commands"

Comment: I did rehash. Is there any way to know if it has worked? Can I see where the Jekyll is installed? I can not find it with *which* command.

Answer (score 3):

#### Following steps solved my problem

```
gem uninstall jekyll
sudo gem install jekyll
```

Open `~/.bash_profile` and add this code in the last line,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.2/bin
```

Save and close the `.bash_profile`

Close and reopen the mac terminal, try running `jekyll` now, it should work