# Trouble installing jekyll on macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll

1. Tried the original method of gem install jekyll and I get this error:

   > > ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
   > >     You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
2. Installed Xcode and command line tools. Then followed up with installing homebrew using this command:

   > > /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
3. get this error after:

   > > Error: Failed to link all completions, docs and manpages:
   > >     Permission denied - (../../../Homebrew/completions/zsh/_brew, /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew)
   > >     Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force
4. These are my ruby and gem version:

   - addressable (2.5.1)
   - bigdecimal (default: 1.2.0)
   - CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
   - colorator (1.1.0)
   - ffi (1.9.18)
   - io-console (default: 0.4.2)
   - jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.0)
   - jekyll-watch (1.5.0)
   - json (default: 1.7.7)
   - kramdown (1.14.0)
   - libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
   - listen (3.0.8)
   - minitest (default: 4.3.2)
   - nokogiri (1.5.6)
   - psych (default: 2.0.0)
   - public_suffix (2.0.5)
   - rake (default: 0.9.6)
   - rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
   - rb-inotify (0.9.10)
   - rdoc (default: 4.0.0)
   - rubygems-update (2.6.12)
   - sass (3.5.1)
   - sass-listen (4.0.0)
   - sqlite3 (1.3.7)
   - test-unit (default: 2.0.0.0)

Please help!

Comment: What do you get if you run `stat /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/`?

Comment: I get 16777220 44348653 drwxr-xr-x 8 root wheel 0 272 "Aug 20 22:13:07 2017" "Aug 18 14:47:41 2017" "Aug 18 14:47:41 2017" "Jul 30 15:04:26 2016" 4096 0 0 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/

Comment: Weird, those are the same permissions as on my system, and it was able to install for me. Also, you might want to include your `ruby` and `gem` versions in the question.

Comment: Does this have something to do with SIP? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33059347/2397550

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running the command with `sudo` ? for example `sudo gem install jekyll bundler`. This will ensure that you're running the command as an administrator.